# How do I determine the crystal field splitting for an arbitrary point group?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, symmetry, group-theory

How can I figure out the degeneracy of the d orbitals for a site that has a given point group? Specifically I'm interested in $D_{3d}$ and $D_{3h}$, but it would be good to know how to do it in the general case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already know the symmetry of your site then it is quite easy. In a lot of books (e.g. [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470853484) one) and on [this](http://www.webqc.org/symmetry.php) web site you can find the character tables of the point groups supplemented with two additional columns which show the transformation properties of the basis vectors (e.g. $\ce{p}$ orbitals), their rotations and their quadratic combinations (e.g. $\ce{d}$ orbitals). In the following picture I highlighted the important parts in the character table of the $\ce{D_{3\mathrm{h}}}$ group.
So in the $\ce{D_{3\mathrm{h}}}$ group the $\ce{d_{z^2}}$ orbital transforms as the irreducible representation $A_{1}^{'}$ and the $\ce{p_{x}}$ and $\ce{p_{y}}$ orbitals transform as the irreducible representation $\ce{E^{'}}$.

[image]

After you have identified the irreducible representations of the $\ce{d}$ orbitals you can tell their degeneracy by identifying which $\ce{d}$ orbitals belong to the same irreduzible representation. If two or three $\ce{d}$ orbitals belong to the same irreducible representation they are degenerate. In the case of the $\ce{D_{3\mathrm{h}}}$ group shown below this means that $\ce{d_{z^2}}$ forms an energy level of its own, while $\ce{d_{x^2-y^2}}$ and $\ce{d_{xy}}$ (both belonging to $\ce{E^{'}}$) are degenerate and $\ce{d_{xz}}$ and $\ce{d_{yz}}$ (both belonging to $\ce{E^{''}}$) are degenerate. So, your $\ce{d}$ orbitals split into three energy levels, two of which are doubly degenerate, when your site has $\ce{D_{3\mathrm{h}}}$ symmetry.

Comment: It wasn't asked for in the OP, but including some comment about how to determine the relative ordering as well might be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @bobthechemist As far as I know it is not possible to determine an energetic ordering of the levels by symmetry alone. What is possible is to reason that, the more directly the orbital lobes of a certain $\ce{d}$ orbital point towards the ligands the higher is the respective $\ce{d}$ orbital's energy (though this method is not very exact). Do you mean that?

Comment: Yes.  I didn't expect that symmetry alone would be able to determine the energetic ordering.  Unless there's a more clever approach out there without resorting to calculations, visualizing the orbital and ligand positions seems to be the best approach.